# Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid events

Tags: .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

In the Infragistics, is there any event which could catch "After column's pin is changed" for the UltraWinGrid?

For the pin icon, it toggles 'Fixed' of the column of the grid.

I tried to use MouseClick, but it is triggered "Before Column Fixed Changed" instead of "After Column Fixed Changed".

I tried to use AfterColPosChanged, but it is triggered during form init, which is not expected too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct event is AfterColPosChanged. However if you do not need to fire this event during initialization of the grid you can turn off this event via grid's [EventManager](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid~eventmanager) when the initialization starts and turn it back on when initialization is over.

You can also use the mouse events, but you should try MouseDown and MouseUp. This is the order of the events when user clicks over the pin button:

```
MouseDown
BeforColPosChanged
AfterColPosChanged
MouseUp
```

## Edit

If you prefer to use EventManager you should turn off the events in the beggining of load_page and turn it on in the end like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ultraGrid1.EventManager.SetEnabled(GridEventIds.AfterColPosChanged, false);
    // TODO: your code here
    this.ultraGrid1.EventManager.SetEnabled(GridEventIds.AfterColPosChanged, true);
}
```

Comment: mouse up is worked, but I'm interest how EventManager indicate rather or not it is page_load or button click,thanks

Comment: EvenManager does not know if you are in page_load or in button_click. What you can do, if you go with EventManager way is in the very beggining of page_load turn off AfterColPosChanged. Then in the very end of page_load turn on the event. This way whatever happens in page_load AfterColPosChanged will not fire. I've updated my answer with sample sode for this.

Comment: Good to know the trick of the grid eventManager, I stick to MouseUp to prevent unnecessary handling of form_load. Thanks